# i am getting json response in firebug .how to view in extjs i am using 4.2.1 version

Tags: json, jsp, extjs, extjs4

i am getting json response in firebug .how to view in extjs i am using 4.2.1 version
sending request to test.java (servlet page) from extjs
receiving response from test.java to extjs via json array object
i can see response from firebug console but i dont how to get in extjs

```
my app.js 


Ext.onReady(function () {
//  var filterPanel = Ext.create('Ext.panel.Panel', {
//      bodyPadding: 5,  // Don't want content to crunch against the borders
//      width: 300,
//      title: 'Filters',
//      items: [{
//          xtype: 'textfield',
//          fieldLabel: 'User Name',
//          name:'username',
//          value:'anand'
//              
//      }, {
//          xtype: 'textfield',
//          fieldLabel: 'Password',
//          name:'Password',
//          type:'password',
//          value:'anand'
//      },
//     
//        {
//            xtype: 'button',
//            text: 'Login',
//            itemId: 'save',
//            iconCls: 'save'
//        }
//      
//      ],
//      
//     
//  
//  
//      renderTo: Ext.getBody()
//  });
//  
//  




    Ext.create('Ext.form.Panel', {
        title: 'Basic Form',
        renderTo: Ext.getBody(),
        bodyPadding: 5,
        width: 350,

        // Any configuration items here will be automatically passed along to
        // the Ext.form.Basic instance when it gets created.

        // The form will submit an AJAX request to this URL when submitted
        url: 'test',

        items: [{
            xtype: 'textfield',
            fieldLabel: 'Field',
            name: 'uname'
        }],

        buttons: [{
            text: 'Submit',
            handler: function() {
                // The getForm() method returns the Ext.form.Basic instance:
                var form = this.up('form').getForm();
                if (form.isValid()) {
                    // Submit the Ajax request and handle the response
                    form.submit({




                        success: function(form, action) {

                             var data= Ext.JSON.decode(action.response.responseText);
                             alert("Success: " + data.msg);
                            // Ext.Msg.alert('Success', action.result.message);



//                   var data= JSON.parse(action.response.responseText);
//                   console.log(data);
                              //Ext.Msg.alert('Success', action.result.message);
                        },
                        failure: function(form, action) {


                            var data= Ext.JSON.decode(action.response.responseText);
                            alert("Failure: " + data.msg);  
                        }
                    });
                }
            }
        }]
    });


}); // onReady()



servlet code




import java.io.IOException;

import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONObject;



import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

import javax.servlet.*;
import javax.servlet.http.*;

import java.sql.*;

/**
 * Servlet implementation class test
 */
@WebServlet("/test")
public class test extends HttpServlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;




    public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request,
            HttpServletResponse response)
    throws ServletException, IOException
    {



}



    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#HttpServlet()
     */
    public test() {
        super();
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
     */


    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
     */
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub



        String firstname = request.getParameter("uname");




if(firstname != null)
{

    System.out.println(firstname);
    final String JDBC_DRIVER="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver";  
    final String DB_URL="jdbc:mysql://localhost/test";

    //  Database credentials
    final String USER = "root";
    final String PASS = "";


    PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
    String title = "Database Result";
     JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray();
    try{
     // Register JDBC driver
     Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");

     // Open a connection
    Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(DB_URL,USER,PASS);



    try{
        System.out.println("connection established");
    }catch(Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
     // Execute SQL query
     Statement stmt = conn.createStatement();
     String sql;
     sql = "SELECT * FROM emp";
     ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(sql);



     // Extract data from result set
     while(rs.next()){
        //Retrieve by column name





        JSONObject obj = new JSONObject();


        obj.put("ID",rs.getInt("id"));
        obj.put("Name", rs.getString("name"));
        jsonArray.put(obj);


//     

     }
//   out.println("</body></html>");
//
//   // Clean-up environment
//   rs.close();
//   stmt.close();
//   conn.close();

    }catch(Exception e){
     //Handle errors for Class.forName
     e.printStackTrace();
    }//end try



//  
//}
//
//




    response.setContentType("application/json");



    response.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
    System.out.println(jsonArray);



    response.getWriter().println(jsonArray);

    //response.getWriter().println("{success:true, error:'error'}");


    }
    }
}
```

Comment: hello console.log(data) and check in firebug  and you will get exact path to access your data

Comment: [{"Name":"anand","ID":1},{"Name":"manoj","ID":2},{"Name":"mohan","ID":3}]     this is response i get in firebug

Comment: Is my answer working?

Comment: Is the control going into the success method?If so,Why don't you put a debug point in your success function and check the format of the data you are getting?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this code

```
    for(var i=0;data.length;i++){

       alert(data[i].Name);
            alert(data[i].ID);
    }
```

Comment: not working because data is an object .i am in confusion i am going in right way or not .bcz i got response in firbug .but i cant view in alert .

Comment: i got solution now it displaying data in console. now sending that data to store to display in grid .now i am trying on that u have any solution how to view in extjs grid it help for me

Comment: If you found data with my answer accept my answer and it helps people who have the same problem in future